# Efficiently extract values from array using a list of index

Tags: python, python-2.7, performance, list, numpy

Given a 2D NumPy array `a` and a list of indices stored in `index`, there must be a way of extracting the values of the list very efficiently. Using a for loop as follows take about 5 ms which seems extremely slow for 2000 elements to extract:

```
import numpy as np
import time

# generate dummy array 
a = np.arange(4000).reshape(1000, 4) 
# generate dummy list of indices
r1 = np.random.randint(1000, size=2000)
r2 = np.random.randint(3, size=2000)
index = np.concatenate([[r1], [r2]]).T

start = time.time()
result = [a[i, j] for [i, j] in index]
print time.time() - start
```

How can I increase the extraction speed? `np.take` does not seem appropriate here because it would return a 2D array instead of a 1D array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [*advanced indexing*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) which basically means extract the row and column indices from the `index` array and then use it to extract values from `a`, i.e. `a[index[:,0], index[:,1]]` -

```
%timeit a[index[:,0], index[:,1]]
# 12.1 µs ± 368 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit [a[i, j] for [i, j] in index]
# 2.22 ms ± 105 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be [`numpy.ravel_multi_index`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ravel_multi_index.html), which lets you avoid the manual indexing.

```
np.ravel_multi_index(index.T, a.shape)
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be even faster because I can use `indexT = index.T` (once for all).